# Extracting tablenames after From clause in sql query

Tags: sql, unix

I have multiple sql.txt files (close to 7000) from which I have to extract table names occurring after from clause on after a particular line number

e.g

```
UPDATE  WT_Table
FROM   (SELECT a.col,
                b.col,
                c.col,
                a.col,
                a.col,
                 FROM    (SELECT Code,
                        Transaction_Date,
                        Transaction_Time,
                        Till_Number,
                        Transaction_Number,
                        SUM(App_Payment),
                        MIN(Item_Line_Number)
                FROM    **WT_work table**
                          **WT_Work_table1**
                             **WT_Work_table2**
```

Is there any possible script through which the table name occurring after the from clause can be extracted to a temporary file

Comment: This is not actually a SQL issue. You basically need to ascertain a way you can search for specific content (in your case FROM line) in a file(s) using unix/linux.
See if this helps in any way:
http://www.livefirelabs.com/unix_commands/10-unix-grep-command-examples-of-how-to-search-a-file-for-a-pattern.htm

Please note I am not a unix person.

Comment: I believe `sed` can help you (maybe compared with `awk` or `grep`).